# popstate - need to click twice on back button to actually get back on react-native

Tags: reactjs, back-button, navigator, popstate

working on single page appliction trying use popstate to navigate back to previous page but I have to click twice to take me back. I want to make it happen for one click. console showing for each click but needs twice click to navigate back. using react native.

also using props.navigator.push for single page application

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => { console.log( event) });
  }, []);
```